# Reflection of curve.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let the curve C be the mirror image of the parabola $y^2= 4 x$ with respect to the line $x+y+4=0$. If A and B are the points of intersection of C with the line $y=-5$, then the distance between A and B is. Answer =4.

I have solved it as, first translating the coordinate to  (-2,-2), then reflecting it on the translated x-axis then rotating it anticlockwise with the angle $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ and at last translating the coordinate back to the former one. Curve $C$ Can be written as in parametric form.Does this reflection preserves the shape.

$\left[ \matrix{ x \cr y}\right]$=$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$.$\left[ \matrix{ t^2+2 \cr -(2t+2) }\right]$-$\left[ \matrix{ -2\cr -2}\right]$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Shift along x-axis by 4 units.

$$ y^2 = 4 (x - 4) = 4 x - 16  $$

has inverse function curve about $ (x= - y )$

$$ - x^2 = 4 y - 16 $$

@ $ y = -5 $ you have roots $ x = \pm 6 $

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to compute the transformation of the parabola. Since the question is about a distance between points, and this is preserved by a reflection, you can apply the the reflection again to the final configuration in which the points $A,B$ were determined. This gives you back your original parabola, and reflection of the line $y=-5$ with respect to $x+y+4=0$ gives the line $x=1$ (which is the unique line with constant value of $x$ that contains the point $(1,-5)$ on the axis of reflection). The points of intersection of $y^2=4x$ with $x=1$ are easily determined; they have $y=\pm2$.

The points $A,B$ themselves are not those points $(1,-2)$ and $(1,2)$ of intersection, but rather their images by the reflection, which happen to be $(-2,-5)$ and $(-6,-5)$.